# How to filter a part of an output in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm struggling with filtering the sessionId from the following output:

```
status  messages                           data
------  --------                           ----
Success {@{code=success; message=Success}} @{sessionId=0662c4d429bb51ef772e875f9c9b3a46; faSessionId=qfvio0382283ihbknhfh70kvn4; phpSessionId=qfvio0382283ihbknhfh70kvn4}
```

I've tried with the following:

```
$sessionId = $response | select "data"
```

This is returning:

```
data
----
@{sessionId=f77d5bfb5bdc65163e605d9c7edbcaed; faSessionId=hrsbd5iuq8i6dttfhimpm5baf1; phpSessionId=hrsbd5iuq8i6dttfhimpm5baf1}
```

I can't get it working to only extract the sessionId part.

It would be great if anyone could assist with the correct PowerShell code to obtain this.

Comment: `$sessionId = $response.data.sessionId`

Comment: @RoadRunner has the right solution. The 'data' property is just another PowerShell object which has properties of it's own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might help to think of the object you're working with like this, in JSON.

```
{
    "Status":  "Success",
    "Messages":  {
                     "code":  "success",
                     "message":  "Success"
                 },
    "Data":  {
                 "faSessionId":  "qfvio0382283ihbknhfh70kvn4",
                 "phpSessionId":  "qfvio0382283ihbknhfh70kvn4",
                 "sessionId":  "0662c4d429bb51ef772e875f9c9b3a46"
             }
}
```

You want the sessionId propeerty so you're selecting `Data`, but then you're finding that `Data` actually has those other properties of `phpSessionId` and `faSessionId`.  Fortunately you have two approaches to get what you need.

**Continue using the `Select-Object` cmdlet**

You are already using this cmdlet but using the alias of `Select`, so you can keep using `Select-Object` to drill down all the way to the center of the Earth basically.

```
$response | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Data | Select-Object -ExpandProperty sessionId
>0662c4d429bb51ef772e875f9c9b3a46
```

**Drill into the property you want with Dereferencing**

This is the more *programmery* way to do it but is very popular. It's also called dot-notation.

```
$response.Data.sessionId
0662c4d429bb51ef772e875f9c9b3a46
```